# jQuery, Check if input value comes from textbox inside footer in table

Tags: jquery, html-table, textbox

I need to apply a special function with jQuery in case the input value comes from a textbox inside the footer of a table. I'm trying to figure out a jQuery condition to find it out.

```
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="desc[]" onkeyup = "InputChanged(this)">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="duration[]" onkeyup = "InputChanged(this)">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="start[]" class="start" onkeyup = "InputChanged(this)">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="wait[]" onkeyup = "InputChanged(this)">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="end[]" onkeyup = "InputChanged(this)">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="phone[]" onkeyup = "InputChanged(this)">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

The jQuery function should go like this:

```
<script>
    function InputChanged(control) {
        if (...) {

        }
        else {

        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You can select all of the footer inputs using `$('tfoot input')`. if it isn't what you're looking for, please tell us a little more of what you want to do. Please take a minute to read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Give those text inputs a unique class and use that for selection

Comment: I just added some more information about the issue @ChristianValentin

Comment: You can use `$('tfoot input').on('keyup', function() { InputChanged($(this).val()); });`. Then the function `InputChanged` will receive the value of the input as parameter every time the input changes, but don't forget to remove the `onkeyup` attribute from the input HTML. See example here https://jsfiddle.net/th2mxcy0/

Comment: @ChristianValentin nice answer

Comment: Good! I'll post an answer so others can see easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```js
$('tfoot input').on('keyup', function() { 
    InputChanged($(this).val()); 
});
```

Then the function `InputChanged` will receive the value of the input as parameter every time the input changes, but don't forget to remove the `onkeyup` attribute from the input HTML.

Follow the example:

```js
var labels = $('tbody td');
$('tfoot input').on('keyup', function() {
  var $t = $(this);
  UpdateParagraph(labels.eq($t.parent().index()), $t.val());
});

function UpdateParagraph(el, value) {
  el.html(value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>desc</td>
        <td>duration</td>
        <td>start</td>
        <td>wait</td>
        <td>end</td>
        <td>phone</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="desc[]" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="duration[]" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="start[]" class="start" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="wait[]" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="end[]" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="phone[]" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```